# get rank of specific users in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of all users and I have another array which has subset of that table.
Ex:table contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

my users:  2,4,6,8,10:

Ranking of my users among themselves w.r.t points and has nothing to do with 1,3,5,7,9

I currently have this table:

```
create table uservotes(id int, name varchar(50), vote int);

INSERT INTO uservotes VALUES
(1, 'A', 34),
(2, 'B', 80),
(3, 'bA', 30),
(4, 'C', 8),
(5, 'D', 4),
(6, 'E', 14),
(7, 'F', 304),
(8, 'AA', 42),
(9, 'Ab', 6),
(10, 'Aa', 10);
```

How do I get ranking among 2,4,6,8,10

Answer I am looking for:

```
id    rank    votes   name
2       1       80     B
4       5        8     C
6       3       14     E
8       2       42     AA
10      4       10     Aa
```

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is what you want:

```
select uv.*, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
from uservotes uv cross join
     (select @rank := 0) const
where uv.id in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
order by votes desc;
```

This is the standard way of calculating a rank efficiently in MySQL, along with a `where` clause to choose your ids.

EDIT:

Before starting, in most databases you would simply use `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` for this purpose.  MySQL does not support this ANSI standard functionality.

The key is the variable `@rank`.  The subquery `const` initializes this to 0.  Then the query run.  The `where` clause gets only the rows you are interested in.  The `order by` then puts them in order by votes, with the biggest votes first.  Finally, the `@rank := @rank + 1 as rank` both updates the `@rank` variable and assigns it to a column in the output.

Comment: Awesome.Can you explain what is uv ? please. And can you explain the entire query briefly.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop a sql question with an dynamic variable
something like

```
select * from `uservotes` where id = $someones_id
```

$someones_id could be an array for an example