# top contibuting users for particular category

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to find top contributors of particular state:
The candidates below have gathered particular votes for that state.
Find Top candidates for that states.

```
create table uservotes(id int, name varchar(50), vote int,state int);

INSERT INTO uservotes VALUES
(1, 'A', 34,1),
(2, 'B', 80,1),
(3, 'bA', 30,1),
(4, 'C', 8,1),
(5, 'D', 4,1),
(6, 'E', 14,2),
(7, 'F', 304,2),
(8, 'AA', 42,3),
(9, 'Ab', 6,3),
(10, 'Aa', 10,3);
```

States

```
create table states(state_id int, name_state varchar(50));

INSERT INTO states VALUES
(1, 'CA'),
(2, 'AL'),
(3, 'AZ'),
```

I am looking for:

for

```
CAL
2
1
3
4
5
```

based on the ranks of contribution.
How do I get that.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in Advance.

Code tried :

```
select uv.*, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
from uservotes uv,states s cross join
     (select @rank := 0) const  on uv.statesid = s.state_id
where name_state = 'CAL'
order by vote desc;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get rank of specific users in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210623/get-rank-of-specific-users-in-mysql)

Comment: its not the same .its the top users of particular category not all users withing specific subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy.  You can use `join` and a `group_concat()`:

```
select name_state, substring_index(group_concat(id order by votes desc), ',', 5)
from uservotes uv join
     states s
     on uv.state = s.state
group by name_state;
```

`group_concat()` will put all the id's in order with the highest votes first.  `substring_index()` will extract the first five.

EDIT:

To get the top ranked users in one row, just add a `where name_state = 'CA'` to the above query.

To get them in different rows:

```
select uv.*
from uservotes uv join
     states s
     on uv.state = s.state
where state = 'CA'
order by votes desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: get top ranked users for one particular state.ie:In this case "CAL"

Comment: @jason . . . I don't know what that comment means.  Edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have changed the comment above .Is it ok?

Comment: I have changed the column in the question too .I want it row wise sorry for confusion of substring format.Basically I need all top users contributing to state="CAL" .Thats ALL.Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: The above code does not have rank column ?How do I add that ?

Comment: @jason . . . by putting in the `cross join` subquery and calculation in the `select` clause.

Comment: I have updated the code tried in my question above and its not working I added both cross join and select rank .Why am I not getting rank? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Unable to rank .Can you please look into it.Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer you suggested but the ranking table I am getting is not correct

Comment: I am getting rank 6,2,1,3,5 instead of 1,2,3,4,5 for the same id .Why I am getting wrong rank for the same code?

Comment: posted new Q:Pls look into it :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211791/getting-wrong-ranking-column