# my code displays wrong ranking values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting wrong ranking but right values in descending order :

```
create table uservotes(id int, name varchar(50), vote int,state int);

INSERT INTO uservotes VALUES
(1, 'A', 34,1),
(2, 'B', 80,1),
(3, 'bA', 30,1),
(4, 'C', 8,1),
(5, 'D', 4,1),
(6, 'E', 14,2),
(7, 'F', 304,2),
(8, 'AA', 42,3),
(9, 'Ab', 6,3),
(10, 'Aa', 10,3);
```

States

```
create table states(state_id int, name_state varchar(50));

INSERT INTO states VALUES
(1, 'CA'),
(2, 'AL'),
(3, 'AZ');
```

using the code below and I am getting rank as 6,2,1,3,5 and not 1,2,3,4,5 why? also the value are correct not the ranks.Please let me know where my mistake is.
I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
select uv.*,
      @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
from  uservotes uv cross join 
     states s 
     on uv.state = s.state_id, (select @curRank := 0) const
where name_state = 'CA'
order by vote desc limit 5;
```

Comment: does the `DESC` give it away?

Comment: I dont know does not look like it .can you suggest anything

Comment: remove the `desc` bit

Comment: 'getting wrong ranking column' -Is it me or does that sound rude?

Comment: removing **desc** does not help

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle if it helps someone else answer this question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c6c/7

Comment: thanks Shiva.Can you solve this ?

Comment: the rank is applied before the rows are ordered, and before the limit as well

Comment: @Sebas can you correct the code above please .Currently very confused

Comment: Check out my answer. Is that what you want? I separated the `vote` query into it's own resultset and applied the ranking on it's results. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: An ENUM field would avoid the need for a cross join or subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It works as shown in this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c6c/33

```
select agg.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank from
(
select uv.*
from uservotes uv cross join 
 states s 
 on uv.state = s.state_id
where name_state = 'CA'
order by vote desc limit 5) as agg, (select @curRank := 0) const;
```

**Results:**

```
ID  NAME    VOTE    STATE   RANK
2   B   80  1   1
1   A   34  1   2
3   bA  30  1   3
4   C   8   1   4
5   D   4   1   5
```